# Laravel 5.5 - The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando subir imagenes a un proyecto, despues de subir 2 o 3 imagenes me aparece el error

> The page has expired due to inactivity.   Please refresh and try again.

Me saca de la sesion y al intentar logearme, me vuelva a dar el mismo error, en la version 5.4 funcionaba bien, hubo algun cambio?

en la consola del navegador me aparece este error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status)

Mi funcion create es:

```
public function create(CreateMessageRequest $request){

      $image = $request->file('image');

      $user = $request->user();

      $message = Message::create([

        'image' => $image->store('messages','public'),

        'content' => $request->input('message'),

        'user_id' => $user->id,

      ]);
```

El formulario tiene:

```
<div class="row">
<form class="" action="/message/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="message" value="" placeholder="Que Estas Pensando?">
  </div>
  <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image">
</form>
```

Comment: estuve investigando y parece que en la version 5.5 este error aparece si hay un token missmatch o algo asi.  https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18728/files

Comment: Si el middleware `VerifyCsrfToken` da muchos problemas, puedes quitarlo de `app\Http\Kernel.php` en la clave "web" de la variable `middlewareGroups`, mientras buscas una solución o entiendes bien como funciona.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné. El problema es que apretaba muy rapido el boton de crear el articulo, hay un proceso que hace laravel de cargar la imagen que dura 1 a 2 segundos y yo apretaba el boton muy rapido.

Comment: De todas maneras, esa no es una solucion! No puedes decirle a  un usuario, e! no aprietes tan rapido...

Comment: le puse un iconito de carga con javascript jajaja

Answer (score 0):

En la versión 5.5 de Laravel "TokenMismatch" genera una excepción o mensaje más "amigable" junto con el código 419, mientras en las versiones anteriores se generaba un error 500 que según quienes hacen Laravel, era menos coherente y no reflejaba la realidad de un problema de Token.

Estuve revisando el código de Laravel 5.5 y comparándolo con Laravel 5.4 y aparentemente ni la generación del Token (en el administrador de sesión) ni la comprobación del mismo (Middleware VerifyCrsfToken) cambiaron.

No he tenido tu problema, pero la solución provisional que dan en algunos sitios es **limpiar el caché del browser (cookies y etc.)**, sin embargo parecería no ser lo ideal, al menos para producción.

Comment: probe limpiar el navegador y me funciono pero despues de un tiempo vuelve a fallar, probé agregando la excepción en "verifycsrftoken.php", pero en vez del error me manda a la pantalla de login, estoy en la misma

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza con **composer update** la ultima versión de 5.5 ya te aparecerá un mensaje mas amigable y te redireccionara a sistema de loqueo

sin embargo revisa el archivo *Handler* ubicado en *app/Exceptions* y debes tener un método como este, si no agrégalo

```
/**
     * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }
```

deberias tener la version

```
$ php artisan --version
```

**Laravel Framework 5.5.17**
que soluciona este error